# Write a for loop for simple awk command (linux)

Tags: linux, loops, awk

**Question:**
I am trying to find multiple specific lines in a file (species) and then print only the 5th line after each species name to a new file. I can do this fine for each species individually, but I am having trouble making a loop to go through each of the 1000 species I have in the document. 
For example:

`awk 'c&&!--c;/species_1$/{c=5}' results.out > speciesnames`

How can I make this command into a loop so that it does the following (iterates over every species in the file):

species 1, print 5th line to document titled speciesnames

species 2, print 5th line to document titled speciesnames

species n, print 5th line to document titled speciesnames

Any help would be appreciated. I have very little experience with loops.
Thanks

**Data structure example from results.out:**

```
Query= species_1

length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevant info
description
description
description
description
description
description
description
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
nucleotides
data
data
data
data
data
data

Query= species_2

length=341
```

.......

**Desired output into file speciesnames:**

```
Line 5, relevant info for species 1
Line 5, relevant info for species 2
Line 5, relevant info for species n
```

Comment: waht's the context of results.out? Do you have to print just 5th line of results?

Comment: The context is that each species has about 50 lines of text associated with it, but that I only need the 5th line extracted.

Comment: The "tr" command can skip lines, and it has a looping capability.

Comment: printing the words `description` and `nucleotides` 20 times to try to describe your input is not nearly as useful as showing some actual data. Show at least 3 small blocks of representative data for sample input, one for each of 3 different species and each block being 5 or 6 lines. Also, show the output you want given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meybe some like this:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/species_[0-9]+$/{c=5}' file
```

---

```
awk '/species_[0-9]+/{a[NR+5]} {b[NR]=$0} END {for (i in a) print b[i]}' file
```

This prints all line 5 lines after hits of `species`.
Do to the nature of `array` in `awk` output is randomized.

Adjusting code after new input:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/species [0-9]+$/{c=4}' file
Line 5, relevent info
```

You did not have `_` between `species` and number, but one space.
You like line `4` after hit, not line `5`

---

Example data:

```
cat file
Query= species 1
length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevent info
description
description
description
description
description
description
Query= species 5
length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevent info need this
description
description
description
description
description
Query= species 8
length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevent info more data
description
description
description
description
description
Query= species 6423
length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevent infom, yes here it is
description
description
description
description
description
```

```
awk 'c&&!--c {print i " --> " $0} /species [0-9]+$/{c=4;i=$2 FS $3}' file
species 1 --> Line 5, relevent info
species 5 --> Line 5, relevent info need this
species 8 --> Line 5, relevent info more data
species 6423 --> Line 5, relevent infom, yes here it is
```

---

Final solution:

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/species_/{c=5}' file
```

Comment: I tried this, but only the first species was retrieved and printed :(

Comment: Can you give some example data, and show what goes wrong.  I see this fails if there are less distance than 5 lines between different `species`

Comment: I have updated my question to show the data structure.

Comment: @user3237139 You need to use code tags `{}` to make your post readable.  I still does not understand what you like to do.

Comment: Thank for adding code tags. 
For each species, I would like to extract the fifth line. 

So instead of doing: 

{awk 'c&&!--c;/species_1$/{c=5}' results.out > speciesnames} 

{awk 'c&&!--c;/species_2$/{c=5}' results.out > speciesnames}

{awk 'c&&!--c;/species_3$/{c=5}' results.out > speciesnames} 

until I have the fifth line for all the species, I would just like to find a loop that would do this through iteration.

Comment: @user3237139 See my example data and output of   `awk`

Comment: While I'm working on your example data and output, I did get awk to work for multiple species like this:  {awk 'c&&!--c;/species_1|species_2/{c=5}' results.out > speciesnames}

Comment: If you need to specify number to get, not just any number use `/species_(1|2|54)/` But your awk have `species_1`, and data have  `species 1` space!!.  Also `c=4` is correct, not  `c=5`.  If this is not true, add new example data with correct input.

Comment: I have changed the example data to show that the underscore is needed (species_1 is correct), also awk is finding the correct line with c=5 because there is a blank line that I had previously not accounted for. Nice pattern example with: {/species_(1|2|54)/}. Unfortunately, it can't skip species. If I do the example above, it will only print the 5th line for species 1 and 2 and exclude 54.

Comment: Solution found: awk 'c&&!--c;/species_()/{c=5}' results.out > speciesnames
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @user3237139 You do not need the parentheses, see my updated post above.  When you have higher reputation you can accept my post or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

an approach using getline function

```
 awk '/^Query *= *species_[0-9]/{print $0":";for(i=1;i<=5;++i){if(getline>0 &&i==5){print}}}' file
```

start loop and get every 5 lines from the line that matches `Query *= *species_[0-90]/`

```
for(i=1;i<=5;++i)
```

Once the 5th line is reached print

```
{if(getline>0 &&i==5){print}}}'
```

example file that has

```
Query= species_1

length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevant info
description
description
data
data
data
data
data
data

Query= species_2

length=341
Score
bits
Line 5, relevant info
description
description
data
data
data
data
data
data
```

result

```
Query= species_1:
Line 5, relevant info
Query= species_2:
Line 5, relevant info
```

Comment: Would you mind tweaking that script to show how to print every input line as it's read to stderr so we can see the script reading every line of the input file for debugging? One of the reasons to avoid using `getline` unnecessarily is that it breaks the natural flow of awks implicit read loop and so makes what should be trivial things like that much harder to do, usually resulting in duplicated code or a complete rewrite. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like

```
linenr=0
species=unknown
cat results.out | while read -r line; do
   if [[ "${line}" = Query* ]]; then
      linenr=0
      species=$(echo ${line} | cut -d= -f2)
   else
      (( linenr = linenr + 1 ))
      if [ ${linenr} -eq 5 ]; then
         echo ${line} > ${species}.out
      fi
   fi
done
```